# How to notify user via telegram in spring boot app&

Tags: spring-boot, telegram, telegram-bot

I have spring boot app which able to notify users via their emails about some events. In mentioned case app is using user email. I need same functionality for telegram - by user nickname or phone number my app have to notify user about event.
How to implement sush simple case?

Comment: https://rieckpil.de/howto-send-telegram-bot-notifications-with-java/

Answer (score 0):

I have already worked on a very large scale project. One of the requirements was to send notifications through various channels, including Telegram Messenger.
You can choose different ways to do this, The solution I can suggest to you is to use the APIs that Telegram itself has to communicate with the core.
I guarantee you that many of your needs will be met through these APIs.
I will share the link that helped me a lot before, I hope I could have helped you.
https://core.telegram.org/api

https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id